# JQuery Show one DIV and hide four another divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how can i make it when i click on one link, show that link but hide another ones.

Here is my code:
[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DoQ0OoQu0w)

It works OK, but after i click on a link i cant navigate to other links it gets stuck there .
Sorry for the long code guys

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#output2").hide();
    $("#output3").hide();
    $("#output4").hide();
    $("#output5").hide();

    $("#home2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output1").hide();
        $("#output2").show();
        $("#output3").hide();
        $("#output4").hide();
        $("#output5").hide();
    })
    $("#home3").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output1").hide();
        $("#output2").hide();
        $("#output3").show();
        $("#output4").hide();
        $("#output5").hide();
    });
    $("#home4").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output1").hide();
        $("#output2").hide();
        $("#output3").hide();
        $("#output4").show();
        $("#output5").hide();
    });
    $("#home5").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output1").hide();
        $("#output2").hide();
        $("#output3").hide();
        $("#output4").hide();
        $("#output5").show();
    });

});

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="output1">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id="home1">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home2">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home3">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home4">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home5">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #dddddd;border-right:1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <p>Home1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output2">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li><a href="#" id="home1">Home1</a></li>
            <li  class="active"><a href="#" id="home2">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home3">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home4">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home5">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #dddddd;border-right:1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <p>Home2</p>
        </div>
    </div><div id="output3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li><a href="#" id="home1">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home2">Home2</a></li>
            <li  class="active"><a href="#" id="home3">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home4">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home5">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #dddddd;border-right:1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <p>Home3</p>
        </div>
    </div><div id="output4">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li><a href="#" id="home1">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home2">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home3">Home3</a></li>
            <li  class="active"><a href="#" id="home4">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home5">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #dddddd;border-right:1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <p>Home4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output5">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li><a href="#" id="home1">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home2">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home3">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home4">Home4</a></li>
            <li  class="active"><a href="#" id="home5">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #dddddd;border-right:1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;">
            <p>Home5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Don't provide a link... provide the code...

Comment: In this link u can find my code :)
http://www.bootply.com/DoQ0OoQu0w

Comment: What if Bootply is down, or goes away? You should *always* post your code in the question.

Comment: We shouldn't have to go anywhere to see your code. It should be on your post.

Comment: StackOverflow is not about today, but to help other people in the future... What if your link goes unavailable in the future?

Comment: OMG sorry, i will post my whole code for 1 minute , i didnt think that way

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Lots of unnecessary code in your bootply.

Check this out (just a smarter way...) http://www.bootply.com/xbuIkoiQZJ

Comment: Check out this smarter way of answering: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Void thanks a lost for the reply, your answer was perfect what i was looking for, but this guy @LcSalazar has some serious manners.
Have a good day guys

Comment: Read the comments on the OP's question... The same is applied to your answer. Never give code-only answers as it may become useless.

Comment: @LcSalazar actually he did help me a lot, and clearly it wasnt useless

Comment: @albaneso - I'm glad you solve your problem, but remember that this site is not just for you... How many others do you think this post is going to help in the future if bootply goes down...?

Comment: Nevermind man @LcSalazar, was just trying to help him.. Sorry if the way was wrong..

Comment: Great @void, you're right in helping... I'm just trying to point you on how to help more people (That's what SO is meant to do)... Think about it: A well formed answer is going to help a lot of other people, and it may get many up-votes in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.bootply.com/JJYUDyFJft

Basically instead of having all of the redundant code in your example it is a better method to have the active class change on each tab click.

Also notice the use of the data-toggle attribute.

You will still need to add in the content that the tabs will go to.

Comment: This isnt what im looking for , it should refresh the whole div not only the active class